why is firewalld not processing rich rules
Using this configuration:
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=myzone
myzone (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.0.10/32
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" destination address="0.0.0.0/0" reject

access to ip address 192.168.0.20 on all ports is being allowed, where it appears it should be rejected, according to the rich rule.
By changing the zone target to reject, all traffic is now rejected, even with a corresponding rich rule which should be allowing the traffic.
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=myzone
myzone (active)
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.0.10/32
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" destination address="0.0.0.0/0" allow

Note that I have tried to add 'priority' values above and below 0, but these have not had any effect.
Why are my rich-rules being ignored?

A rich rule doesn’t work by itself. It only ” extends the current zone elements (service, port, icmp-block, icmp-type, masquerade, forward-port and source-port) with additional source and destination addresses, logging, actions and limits for logs and actions.” Since none of these elements is present in the zone, the rich rule does not work. Overall, if the goal is to manage outgoing traffic, you may need to use a firewalld policy.

Here a sample firewalld policy that should work for the first configuration: firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=mypolicy, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-ingress-zone=HOST, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-egress-zone=ANY, firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=mypolicy --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address = "0.0.0.0/0" drop', firewall-cmd --reload. For the second configuration set the target to REJECT and change the rich rule to accept.

I have a feeling this was being caused by firewalld applying the rules to INPUT instead of FORWARD, since I've now made this work using iptables instead of firewalld, but the rules had to go into FORWARD for it to work.
At any rate, the version of firewalld I was using didn't have the --policy feature so I couldn't try this suggestion...
